# Route around ISP blocking incoming port 80

Tags: networking

My ISP blocks incoming connections to port 80, but I want to run a webserver from a home computer.  I also have a domain name registered.

What are the easiest/best ways to host my site?

My only idea so far is:
pay for a hosting account, set up apache there to route requests from there to my home connection on an open port (eg 8080)

Comment: Get a different ISP.

Comment: Forget it. Just pay a hosting account. No need to do that at home. Low end hosting is dead cheap.

Comment: There are tons of reasons to do this and other people who would be interested in solutions.  Also, almost every broadband ISP in Canada does this.

Comment: Please do us the courtesy of reading the FAQ.

Comment: Question **must** be as least re-tagged. Problem have **nothing common** with **any** used tag. Even just *"apache"* (not "apache2") applicable only partially. It's a question about "dns"  and "SRV-records". But it's offtopic anyway, according to FAQ

Comment: @Will: Rogers doesn't.  But still, check out http://lowendbox.com for dirt cheap (like less than $3 a month) for low-end VPS hosting.  Full root access, static IP, on a 256MB RAM/2GHz slice is more than enough computing for a home site.  And why would you want to subject your home network to potential overage charges if your box gets owned?

Answer (score 2):

Why pay for hosting?  Couldn't you get a free hosting account somewhere, point your domain to it, and then use a simple redirect for all traffic?

I assume this is for a small website you built at home because it was convenient.  Maybe a dev environment or running some scripts you want access to from anywhere.  If you actually want to run a production environment from home AND your provider blocks port 80, you're crazy.

One question would be - do you want to domain name to show up when browsing the site?  If not, simple redirects from domain.com to IP.ADDR.AT.HOME would work just fine (see the following link for all kinds of ways to redirect:  http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html)

If you want your domain name to show up, here's some hacking I would do:

The big problem I see is because you're trying to redirect everything from one server to another, you're gonna have to convert POST arguments to GET (since posting to a 3rd party server which only redirects means your post data will get lost).

If your hosting provider allows some scripting language, you could use PHP or Perl to redirect all requests:

```
<?php
  $args = $_GET;
  $postArgs = $_POST;
  $paramString = (empty($args) ? '' : '?');
  if (empty($args)) $paramString = (empty($postArgs) ? '' : '?');
  $first = true;
  foreach ($args AS $key => $value) {
          $paramString .= (!$first ? '&' : '') . $key . '=' . $value;
          $first = false;
  }
  foreach ($postArgs AS $key => $value) {
          $paramString .= (!$first ? '&' : '') . $key . '=' . $value;
          $first = false;
  }

  $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  header("Location: http://IP.ADDR.AT.HOME:8080$uri$paramString");
?>
```

Really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Free hosts have very bad SEO.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost inconceivable that your ISP both permits you to run a web server and blocks port 80. If your ISP does not permit you to run a web server, then you can't run one. You are trying to find a technical solution to something that is not a technical problem. You do not have the right to run a web server.

Comment: Delirium. Web for internal work may be easy **on** policy, with blocking 80 port on border for internetworking.

Comment: Is it just me, or does this comment make absolutely no sense at all?

Comment: @gravyface I'm not sure what he's trying to say? I think he's saying a  webserver for LAN stuff is ok.